# Get Unity container reference in MVC controller action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, unity-container

Is it possible to get the reference of the unity container used for resolving the Contructor injected paraeters for MVC Controller?

I need the reference of the currently used container, because we have classes which use it.

I am trying to save the reference of the registered during `Application_Start()` handler in the `MvcApplication` class, by storing the container instance in a property in the MvcApplication class, but it's null when i try to access it in the controllers later.

The container is registered like so:

```
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(CurrentUnityContainer));
```

Provided that `CurrentUnityContainer` is a non-static property in the MvcApplication class

Then, in the controller we try to get it by accessing the current MvcApplication instance like so:

```
MvcApplication.Instance.CurrentUnityContainer
```

Any ideas why the container is null in the controller, or other way to get it?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the dependency resolver via `System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver.Current` static property.

But be aware about [Service Locator](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/) anti-pattern.

Comment: Sorry, but I need the container (IUnityContainer), or will have to refactor quite a lot of legacy code.

Comment: Have you tried to cast: `var currentUnityContainer = System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver.Current as UnityDependencyResolver;`?